# Azure Sql Data Sync Group Stuck in "Not Ready" State

Tags: sql, database, azure, synchronization

Created a new Sync Group and Group Stuck in "Not Ready" State
[Staus image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvtId.png)
and
[properties image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiNFW.png)

Comment: use this article to troubleshoot : https://www.sqlcoffee.com/Azure_0012.htm

Comment: Can you add more details or screenshots about how you configure the data sync group? You could first read this official document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-troubleshoot#sync-issues

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvtId.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiNFW.png

Comment: Hi @HASSANNAZEER, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. If you have any other concerns, please feel free to let me know, Thank you.

Comment: @HASSANNAZEER is the issue solved now?

Answer (score 1):

That is caused by you only create the sync group and set the hub database, didn't configure the sync tables:
[image]
[image]

Please click the database icon and table icon to finish the sync settings.
[image]

[image]

Ref:[Tutorial: Set up SQL Data Sync between databases in Azure SQL Database and SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-sql-server-configure)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. That was because the wizard does not create connection  with the "destination" database - you need to do this manually, as described in the Leon's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to approve the private endpoint connection from the Sync Group properties.  Once I did that the group finished creating within seconds.